# odd positions has even numbers and even positions have odd number from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript file, Enter array from user txt1 if even positions has odd numbers that all  numbers should display in txt2 if odd positions has even numbers that all numbers should display in txt3 
here in loop i+2 is not working out and a single digit is displaying at a time but not all even and odd numbers in textboxes:

***WARNING: Do not copy paste and try to run the below code unless you are willing to crash your browser!***

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Enter data
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="b1" value="REsult" onclick="validate()"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
function validate()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value.split(",");
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i+2)
    {
        if(a[i]%2!=0)
        {
            document.getElementById("txt2").value = a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("txt2").value = " ";
        }
    }
        for(var j=1;j<=a.length;j+2)
        {
            if(a[j]%2==0)
            {
                document.getElementById("txt3").value = a[j];
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("txt3").value = " ";
            }
        }

}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[design page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynqoe.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynqoe.png)

Comment: ***DONT RUN THE ABOVE SCRIPT***

Comment: is that in infinite loop?

Comment: What is your question? Just posting a homework problem and code is not a question.

Comment: she want to separate odd and even num of txt1 to txt2 and txt3

Comment: it is an infinite loop

Comment: @Nikhila Please add a warning next time in your question if it has an infinite loop, so that you don't crash browser of users that are willing to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>d</title>
    <style></style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    function validate() {
        var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value.split(",");
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = '';
        document.getElementById("txt3").value = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2) {
            if (a[i] % 2 != 0) {
                document.getElementById("txt2").value += a[i] + ',';
            }
        }
        for (var j = 1; j <= a.length; j += 2) {
            if (a[j] % 2 == 0) {
                document.getElementById("txt3").value += a[j] + ',';
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = document.getElementById("txt2").value.replace(/,$/, '');
        document.getElementById("txt3").value = document.getElementById("txt3").value.replace(/,$/, '');

    }
    </script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Enter data
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt3" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="b1" value="REsult" onclick="validate()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not working I am getting a complete array as a result

Comment: what do you want?seperate odd and even numbers?